# Using raw Cypher to query Neo4j in Symfony

Tags: symfony, neo4j, twig, cypher, neoxygen

I am trying to go throught this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-social-network-features-php-app-neo4j/ But using the Symfony Framework instead of Silex.

I have been able to set up Neo4j to run with Symfony and am able to right user data to the graph. Now I would like to display all user email addresses in a list. I have taken this script:

```
 public function home(Application $application, Request $request)
    {
        $neo = $application['neo'];
        $q = 'MATCH (user:User) RETURN user';
        $result = $neo->sendCypherQuery($q)->getResult();

        $users = $result->get('user');

        return $application['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
            'users' => $users
        ));
    }
```

And adapted it to read:

```
   public function showUsersAction()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('neo4j.manager');
        $query = 'MATCH (n:`User`) RETURN n';
        $users = $em->cypherQuery($query);

        //print_r($users);
        return $this->render('UserBundle:Account:showUsers.html.twig', array('users' =>$users));
    }
```

And The twig looks as follows:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>get all users:</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user.property('email') }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

But something in the twig is wrong, im getting the error:

```
Method "property" for object "Everyman\Neo4j\Query\Row" does not exist in UserBundle:Account:showUsers.html.twig at line 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was found in the syntax of the twig file. After consulting this page: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Cypher-and-gremlin-queries it became clear, that I had to include `user['n']` in my twig template. The twig template now looks as such:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>get all users:</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for user in users %}
        <li>{{ user['n'].getProperty('email') }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the article you mentioned. The thing is that you use a different neo4j library than the one used in the article, hence [neoclient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient), so the methods used in the article are different than the methods provided with neo4jphp.

As NeoClient uses heavily the Symfony components, integrating it in Symfony is really easy, you just need to override the DI. Example here : https://github.com/graphaware/GithubNeo4j/tree/master/src/GraphAware/Neo4jBundle

You'll then be able to use the methods illustrated in the 3 articles I wrote on Sitepoint.

So your problem with the twig template is that he doesn't find the `getProperty` method of the node object class, which is normal as neo4jphp returns Row object classes.

If you switch back to neoclient, as in the article, in the Twig template you can just write :

```
{% for user in users %}
   <li>{{ user.getProperty('email') }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I will have a look into neoclient and the example you mentioned.